# Issue with dropping table which contains special char in tablename. (Linux&Postgres)

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am facing issue with DROP table command in Linux (backend : Postgres). I have a table named "prabhu2016-02-08--2016-02-15". when I drop this table using below commend i am receiving error.... 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: ...op table prabhu2016-02-08--2016-02...

code is: 
psql -d DBname -c "Drop table myschema.prabhu2016-02-08--2016-02-15

Looks like Hyphen issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "partition table"?

Comment: It is a child table.. (inherited table)...

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly then. The term "partition table" might be easily confusing as it usually refers to storage devices rather than DBs.

Comment: have you tried wrapping the table name with single quotes?  e.g. `drop table 'prabhu2016-02-08--2016-02-15';`

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: wrapping the table name with single quotes is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when the query is complex shellwize or I have to use any names/variables that better be quoted:

1. Use all the names as variables: tablename="bla"
2. Call psql this way:

   `su - postgres -c "/usr/local/ctera/postgres/bin/psql << EOF

   drop table "$tablename";

   EOF"`

Comment: Issue is, the table name has (hyphen) - symbol, hence drop command is failing,. how to skip/make hyphen as a word and run the command ?

Comment: any help here ?

Comment: Wait, how did you create this table?

Comment: It is dynamic child table creation. I have a trigger, that will create a Child Table including current_date in table name, whenever new data coming into Parent table. When DB size is full, I need to drop the child table. now I stuck here with drop table command.